# What is the best way to compare two lists in Javascript as you would do in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, optimization, coffeescript

I'm quite new with JavaScript but familiar with python. In Python I get this output:

```
In [1]: [1,9,[5,4,2]] > [1,9,[14,5,4]]
Out[1]: False
```

In JavaScript:

```
> [1,9,[5,4,2]] > [1,9,[14,5,4]]
true
```

It seems that the arrays are converted into a string before the comparison.

Now i wanted to write a function by myself and walk through the array an compare each element.
I came up with this coffeescript code:

```
compare_list = (a, b)->
    if typeof a == "object" and typeof b != "object"
        return 1
    else if typeof a != "object" and typeof b == "object"
        return -1
    else if typeof a != "object" and typeof b != "object"
        if a > b
            return 1
        else if a < b
            return -1
        else
            return 0
    else if typeof a == "object" and typeof b == "object"
        for i in [0...a.length]
            if i > (b.length-1)
                return 1
            tmp = compare_list a[i], b[i]
            if tmp != 0
                return tmp
        if b.length > a.length
            return -1
        return 0
```

It works this way but the `typeof a == "object"` part looks not correct to me. Is there a simpler/better/more robust solution?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solution for what? To check whether a and b are arrays?

Comment: Yes, or if there is a simpler solition.

Comment: Then you should not check for objects, but use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to solve the same issue, I too only came up with a custom solution. https://gist.github.com/ruxkor/2772234

As Javascript is using string coercion when comparing object, I think it is necessary to use a custom comparison function to simulate Python behavior.

Comment: Use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) instead of checking a `constructor` property.

Comment: But I don't think that handles the nested lists the question is looking for.

Comment: Bergi: thanks, updated. 
@ScottSauyet why wouldn't it work? the function calls itself on list elements, pairwise.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, as I'm not really a CoffeeScript person, but it looks to me as though this would yield `cmp([1, 9, [5, 4, 2]], [1, 9, [5, 4]]); // => 0`, which is presumably not right.  It seems to depend upon the lists having exactly the same structure.  I guess it's my interpretation that it should handle this case, as the lists presented do share the same structure...

Comment: @ScottSauyet you are right, thanks! I updated the script and (rudimentary) test accordingly.

Comment: @ruxkor: Yes, that looks much better!

Answer (score 4):

This is basically the same algorithm avoiding the `typeof` operator and doing a little trick in the `for` loop to not check for the lengths of the arrays every time:

```
cmp = (a, b) -> (a > b) - (a < b)

cmpArray = (a, b)->
  aIsArray = Array.isArray a
  bIsArray = Array.isArray b

  return cmp a, b if not aIsArray and not bIsArray
  return -1       if not aIsArray and     bIsArray
  return 1        if     aIsArray and not bIsArray

  # Both are arrays.
  len = Math.min a.length, b.length
  for i in [0...len] by 1
    if tmp = cmpArray a[i], b[i]
      return tmp
  a.length - b.length
```

Unfortunately, CoffeeScript does not provide any sort of pattern matching. That would make this code much more DRY-er. You can fake a poor man's pattern matching using a `switch` statement if you want:

```
cmpArray = (a, b)->
  switch "#{Array.isArray a},#{Array.isArray b}"
    when 'false,false' then (a > b) - (a < b) # Compare primitives.
    when 'false,true' then -1
    when 'true,false' then 1
    else
      len = Math.min a.length, b.length
      for i in [0...len] by 1
        if tmp = cmpArray a[i], b[i]
          return tmp
      a.length - b.length
```

But this is definitely not very idiomatic CoffeeScript. If CoffeeScript supported some kind of pattern matching, i'd definitely go for this kind of slution, as i think it reads very nicely being just a single expression and not relying (too much) on early returns.

Comment: Ah, that's what my loop would look like in CoffeeScript. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make it minimalistic:

```
function compare(a, b) {
    if (a instanceof Array && b instanceof Array) {
        for (var r, i=0, l=Math.min(a.length, b.length); i<l; i++)
            if (r = compare(a[i], b[i]))
                return r;
        return a.length - b.length;
    } else // use native comparison algorithm, including ToPrimitive conversion
        return (a > b) - (a < b);
}
```

(using `instanceof` for Array detection, see [this article](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/) for discussion)

If you want to make objects always greater than primitives, you can change the last line to

```
        return (typeof a==="object")-(typeof b==="object") || (a>b)-(a<b);
```

Comment: Love the minimalism in this one :). A small caveat though: it doesn't behave exactly like the OP's algorithm, as it'll make some toString conversions in the `else` case. E.g. `compare('a,b', ['a', 'b'])` is 0, while it should be -1. I hope you don't bother if i steal the `(a > b) - (a < b)` trick; it's very sexy! =D

Comment: Yeah, it does not exactly behave as the OPs one when types do not match - yet this for example allows comparison of `Date` objects with numbers and similar.

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at implementing a JavaScript function `compareArrays` that behaves like array comparison in Python:

```
function compareArrays(a, b) {
    var aIsArray = Array.isArray(a),
        bIsArray = Array.isArray(b),
        cmp = 0;
    if (!aIsArray || !bIsArray) {
        throw new Error('Can\'t compare array to non-array: ' + a + ', ' + b);
    }

    _.find(a, function (aElem, index) {
        var bElem = b[index];
        if (Array.isArray(aElem) || Array.isArray(bElem)) {
            cmp = compareArrays(aElem, bElem);
        } else {
            cmp = (aElem > bElem) - (aElem < bElem);
        }

        if (cmp !== 0) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    return cmp;
}
```

It uses [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to iterate over arrays, and recurses to handle nested arrays.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/zQtfa/) which includes a primitive test suite.

### Test Results

```
[1,9,[5,4,2]] < [1,9,[14,5,4]]
[1,[1]] can't be compared to [1,1]
[1,[2]] > [1,[1]]
[2] > [1]
[1] == [1]
[] == []
```

Comment: Why `find`, you don't search for anything?

Comment: @Bergi find lets me break early, as opposed to each which does not.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty ugly, but this seems to do the job:

```
var compareLists = function compare(listA, listB) {
    if (Array.isArray(listA)) {
        if (Array.isArray(listB)) {
            if (listA.length == 0) {
                if (listB.length == 0) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                if (listB.length == 0) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return compare(listA[0], listB[0]) || 
                           compare(listA.slice(1), listB.slice(1));
                }
            }
        } else {
            return -1; // arbitrary decision: arrays are smaller than scalars
        }
    } else {
        if (Array.isArray(listB)) {
            return +1; // arbitrary decision: scalars are larger than arrays
        } else {
            return listA < listB ?  -1 : listA > listB ? + 1 : 0;
        }
    }
};

compareLists([1, 9, [5, 4, 2]], [1, 9, [14, 5, 4]]); // -1
compareLists([1, 9, [5, 4, 2]], [1, 9, [5, 4]]);     // +1
compareLists([1, 9, [5, 4, 2]], [1, 9, [5, 4, 2]]);  //  0
```

Depending upon your environment, you might want to shim `Array.isArray`:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = function (obj) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
    };
}
```